# Best way to switch View Controller in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have 2 view controllers in my project. Inside View Controller1 I want to switch to View Controller 2 by press of a button. Currently I do this

```
- (IBAction)startController2:(id)sender {

viewController1 vc2 = [[viewController2 alloc] init];
self.view = vc2.view;
}
```

This seems to work fine, but there is a big delay (4 secs) between the button press and second view controller appears. If I call the viewController2 directly from the AppDelegate things load faster. What am I  doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's definitely wrong to move view controllers views' between view controllers like that. (Each view controller "owns" it's view.)

Comment: you should use navigation controller to push to another viewcontroller

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Several things to consider.

### Part 1: "What am I doing wrong here"?

1. You definitely didn't mean to do `self.view = vc2.view`. You just put one view controller in charge of another view controller's view. What you probably mean to say was `[self.view addSubview:vc2.view]`. This alone might fix your problem, **BUT**...
2. Don't actually use that solution. Even though it's almost directly from the samples in [some popular iPhone programming books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X), it's a bad idea. Read ["Abusing UIViewControllers"](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) to understand why.

### Part 2: What you should be doing

It's all in the chapter ["Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html).

It'll come down to either:

- a UINavigationController, (see the excellent Apple guide to them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1)) and then you simply `[navigationController pushViewController:vc2]`
- a "manually managed" stack of modal view controllers, as [andoabhay suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265432/768176)
- explicitly adding a VC as child of another, as [jason suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265430/768176)

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using `UINavigationController` to switch view controllers. If your building target is iOS 5.0+, you can also use the new controller container concept: `[mainViewController addChildViewController:childViewController]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `presentModalViewController` as follows

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

and in the `viewController1` use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

where ever you want to go back to previous controller.

Comment: This approach is deprecated now

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: is the new way to use this paradigm

Answer (score 0):

```
[aController presentViewController:bController animated:NO completion:nil];
[bController presentViewController:cController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

when you want dismiss cController, you can do like this

```
[aController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

this is the flow chart.

```
aController → bController → cController
    ↑___________________________↓
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use UINavigationController to switch view controllers.

You are on View1 and add the following code on button click method.

`View2 *View2Controller = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2Controller animated:YES];`